# Listen to the user with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am making a Cordova App, and one of the requirements is to be able to hear the user.

I followed the example [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio), but then I discovered it is not what I expected. It throws a Record message intent in Android, but I need something like the speech recognition popup (the "Talk now" popup), even if it skips the speech recognition process (in fact, I would skip it).

Is there a way to listen to the user with Cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Sorry I didn't notice you already followed this tutorial. But what you can do is write a CordovaPlugin for this puropse, with this you would have full control over everything that happens.
Your second option would be to just react to the intent that is sent by cordova, but in both cases you would have to handle the recording of audio yourself which can be tricky to get to work on a large spectrum of devices.
Either way you decide, I can help you and set you on the right track.

**Original Answer:**

Yes there is, you have to add this to your plugin.xml:

```
<plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
```

And add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And then you can record like this:

```
// capture callback
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        // do something interesting with the file
    }
};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
};

// start audio capture
navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:2});
```

You can find more information on the topic [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html)